# Alterar posição do texto em text area

Tags: html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou a fazer um formulário de contactos, no qual tenho uma texarea que é onde ira ser introduzida a mensagem, mas eu quero que a palavra "mensagem" apareça em cima conforme mostra a imagem, alguém que me possa ajudar por ai?

e queria assim.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho o seguinte código

```
<textarea rows="3" class="notes" id="mensagem" name="mensagem" ></textarea> Mensagem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque o texto "Mensagem" dentro de um `label` e use a propriedade `vertical-align: top` através de uma classe.

Veja:

```css
.valign-top{
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="3" class="notes" id="mensagem" name="mensagem"></textarea>
<label class="valign-top">Mensagem</label>
```

Comment: não eu quero a "mensagem" logo apos a primeira linha, eu editei a perguta para melhor entendimento.

Comment: @Roberto Editei novamente a resposta. Acho que entendi melhor o que vc quer fazer.

Comment: muito obrigado, ajudou bastante era mesmo isso que pretendia.